# How to print only the final result of this array operation?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I only want to print the last result of this operation, that would be 10. How I can do that?

```
result = 0
numbers = [1,2,3,4]
numbers.map do |x|
  result += x
  puts result
end
```

Comment: 1. Change `map` to `each`. 2. Change `+ =` to `+=`. 3. Swap the positions of the last two lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
puts [1,2,3,4].inject(0, &:+)
```